# ST_LineInterpolatePoint Error - Does not exist

Tags: postgis, snapping, st-dwithin

I am having an issue 'snapping' a points layer (be - bristol education) onto a road network (br - bristol_roads). I have created the code below using the PostGIS in Action guidebook as a reference however when I execute the code I receive this error -

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (be.id)
  br.geom AS br_geom,
  be.geom AS be_geom,
  br.gid AS br_id,
  be.id AS be_id,
  ST_Line_Locate_Point(
  br.geom,
  ST_Line_Interpolate_Point(br.geom, be.geom)
  ) AS snapped_point
  FROM bristol_education AS be INNER JOIN
  bristol_roads AS br
  ON
  ST_DWithin(be.geom, br.geom, 1)
  ORDER BY
  be.id, ST_Distance(br.geom, be.geom);

ERROR:  function st_lineinterpolatepoint(geometry, geometry) does not exist
LINE 8:   ST_LineInterpolatePoint(br.geom, be.geom)
          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 147
```

Does anyone know how I can get around this? I have tried snapping the points in arcmap/qgis but it seems that PostGIS does not pick up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's note that the functions are [`ST_LineLocatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html) and [`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html). The signature in your query are now obsolete.

That being said, `ST_LineLocatePoint` takes a geometry and a point and return the fraction (line length %) of the nearest point projection on the line.

`ST_LineInterpolatePoint` takes a line and a fraction (line length %) and return the point located at this fraction.

In your query, it seems the two functions have been swapped